# Grammatik in Konjunktiv mit Passivform

Tags: grammar, subjunctive, passive

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Würde Deutschland die Sterbehilfe so umsetzen, würde dem Sterbetourismus zusätzlicher Aufwind beschert.

Weil der zweiter Teil des Satzes ein Passivsatz ist, müsste man nicht

> ..., würde dem Sterbetourismus zusätzlicher Aufwind beschert **werden**.

schreiben?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es sind beide Varianten möglich. Der Indikativ lautet ja

> Aufwind wird beschert.

Die verschiedenen Konjunktivformen sind:

> **Konjunktiv I:** Aufwind werde beschert.
>   **Konjunktiv II:** Aufwind würde beschert.
>   **würde-Konjunktiv:** Aufwind würde beschert werden.

In der Irrealis-Verwendung können nur Konjunktiv II und der würde-Konjunktiv verwendet werden. Stilistisch ist meines Erachtens die Konjunktiv-II-Variante zu bevorzugen, um eine Verdoppelung des Verbs *werden* zu vermeiden.

Answer (score 4):

Kurze Antwort: Nein. Der Konjunktiv mit *würde* ist ja nur eine Hilfskonstruktion, die der Autor hier im ersten Teilsatz gewählt hat.
Diese Hilfskonstruktion wird oft als wenig elegant angesehen, hat aber den Vorteil, daß der Autor lediglich den Konjunktiv von *werden* kennen muß, das eigentliche Verb erscheint dann im Infinitiv. Prinzipiell könnte man (würde man können…) diese Konstruktion auch anwenden, um den Konjunktiv von werden zu bilden, aber hier ist kein Vorteil mehr zu erkennen: anstelle den Konjunktiv von *werden* zu bilden, nimmt man den Konjunktiv von *werden* und den Infinitiv…

In meinen Augen allemal eleganter ist es, in beiden Satzteilen den Konjunktiv direkt zu bilden:

> Setzte Deutschland die Sterbehilfe so um, würde dem Sterbetourismus zusätzlicher Aufwand beschert.

Comment: "würde" ist nicht "nur" eine "Hilfskonstruktion", sondern die "analytische Konstruktion" des Konjunktiv II. Demnächst spricht man auch vom Perfekt als "Hilfskonstruktion" oder besser noch, "modale Verwendung von 'haben'" \*schauder*.

Answer (score 2):

Im Falle von umsetzen wird die analytische Konjunktiv-II-Form bevorzugt, da der flektierte Konjunktiv II mit dem Präteritum zusammenfällt:

> Würde Deutschland die Sterbehilfe umsetzen,
>   Täte Deutschland die Sterbehilfe umsetzen, (Dialekt)

Im zweiten Falle hat man mit *werden* ein Verb, das als "würde" über eine flektierte und vom Präteritum unterscheidbare Verbform verfügt:

> würde dem Sterbetourismus zusätzlicher Aufwind beschert. (Konjunktiv II)
>   wurde dem Sterbetourismus zusätzlicher Aufwind beschert. (Präteritum)

Aus stilistischen Gründen nimmt man die gebeugte Form des Konjunktivs, wenn es sie gibt und sie nicht allzu veraltet klingt (stürbe, lüde, hülfe).
Die Besonderheit ist jedoch, dass im zweiten Satze Hilfsverb und regiertes Hauptverb gleich sind. Bei der analytischen Konjunktiv-II-Form hat man dadurch die Möglichkeit, "würde werden" oder "würde" zu nehmen. Das ist insofern interessant, als dass das mit dem Futur ohne Bedeutungsveränderung nicht möglich ist:

> Die Sterbehilfe wird in Deutschland umgesetzt, deshalb wird dem Sterbehilfetourismus Aufwind beschert werden. (Futur + Futur).
>   Die Sterbehilfe wird in Deutschland umgesetzt, deshalb wird dem Sterbehilfetourismus Aufwind beschert. (Futur + Präsens).

Der Unterschied zwischen "werden + INF" und "würde + INF liegt" darin, dass "werden + INF" eine Verbform bildet, die das Hauptverb von sich aus nicht bilden kann. "würde + INF" ist hingegen nur der Träger der Eigenschaft "Konjunktiv", die jedes deutsche Verb noch mehr oder minder deutlich selbst bilden kann. Deswegen ist "würde" *noch* optional und es gibt den etwas seltsamen Fall, dass "würde" seinen eigenen Konjunktiv II analytisch bilden kann.

Answer (score 1):

Die ursprüngliche Frage scheint gar nicht richtig verstanden worden zu sein.
Muss man in dem zweiten Teil des Satzes Futur benutzen, weil der zweite Teil eine Folge ausdrückt?
Die Antwort ist nein.

Ja, Futur Passiv ist "es wird Aufwind beschert werden" mit 2 werden.
Und damit wäre der Konjunktiv II davon natürlich "würde... werden".

Es geht also nicht darum, ob man die analytische oder die flektierte Form benutzen sollte, sondern ob man hier die Futur-Form des Konjunktivs benutzen muss.
Die flektierte Konjunktiv-II-Form von werden ist schließlich würde. Wenn es zwei werden gibt, dann muss das flektierte in den Konjunktiv II gesetzt werden.

Die Futur-Form wird bei schwachen Verben gerne als Ersatzform benutzt, damit es keine Verwirrung mit dem Präteritum gibt. Hier geht es aber darum, ob die Präsens-Form reicht...

Ich würde sagen, ja, das reicht. Wir nehmen es in solchen Situationen auf Deutsch nicht so genau.

"Wenn du das machst, bestehst du die Prüfung." Hier könnte man ein werden einsetzen, um die Folge zu betonen. "..., dann wirst du die Prüfung bestehen."

Das hat Null mit gutem Stil zu tun. Es ist einfach auf Deutsch so, dass die Zukunft durch das Präsens ersetzt wird, wenn der Kontext die Zukünftigkeit schon zu Genüge vermittelt.

Deshalb hat der Autor das zweite werden, was rein theoretisch benötigt wird, um die Zukünftigkeit anzuzeigen, weggelassen.

Oder der Spiegel-Autor hatte keine Ahnung von der deutschen Grammatik und hat deshalb hyperkorrigiert, was mich bei einem Spiegelartikel überhaupt nicht verwundern würde. Man kann ja schon froh sein, wenn die ihre Texte Korrektur lesen lassen.

Lange Rede kurzer Sinn: Ja, ein zweites werden ist OK, aber man braucht es nicht.

Comment: Ich stimme dem inhaltlich überwiegend zu, für mich liest sich die Frage (unter besonderer Berücksichtigung des Titels) aber so, dass es um das erste *werden* für Passiv geht und nicht um ein zweites für Futur.