# "würde" vs "würde ... werden": Häufigkeit der Konjunktiv II Form von "werden"

Tags: usage, subjunctive

Wenn der Indikativ

> Aufwind wird beschert.

lautet, kann man den Konjunktiv II mit entweder

> (a) Aufwind würde beschert.

oder

> (b) Aufwind würde beschert werden.

bilden. (Siehe auch [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18173/grammatik-in-konjunktiv-mit-passivform).)

Welche Form wird eigentlich häufiger in der Sprache verwendet, und um wie viel? In diesem Fall scheint es schwer, die Häufigkeit durch Datenbanken wie Google N-gram festzustellen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ganz allgemein gilt laut verschiedenen Bänden des *Duden* die *würde*-Form (*würde* + Infinitiv) als typisches Kennzeichen der gesprochenen Umgangssprache. Allmählich dringt die Konstruktion auch in die Standardsprache vor.

Die *würde*-Form dient hauptsächlich als Ersatz für ungebräuchliche oder nicht eindeutige Konjunktivformen. Vor allem viele Konjunktiv-II-Formen mit Umlaut sind ungebräuchlich, weil sie als gehoben, geziert oder altertümlich empfunden werden.

Speziell für die Ersetzung des Konjunktivs II von „werden“ („würde …“) durch die entsprechende *würde*-Form („würde … werden“) trifft diese Begründung aber nicht zu.

Die *würde*-Form von „werden“ tritt allerdings trotzdem auf. In der Standardsprache dient sie insbesondere als Ersatz für den Konjunktiv Futur des Vollverbs „werden“ („werden werde“)

> Er glaubte, dass dieser Schritt ohnehin unvermeidlich *werden werde.*
>   → Er glaubte, dass dieser Schritt ohnehin unvermeidlich ***werden würde.***
>   (Er glaubte, dieser Schritt *werde* ohnehin unvermeidlich *werden.*)

sowie für den Konjunktiv Futur Passiv („[…] werden werde“).

> Aus dem Justizministerium verlautete, dass das Urteil vorerst nicht *vollstreckt werden werde.*
>   → Aus dem Justizministerium verlautete, dass das Urteil vorerst nicht *vollstreckt **werden würde.***
>   (Aus dem Justizministerium verlautete, das Urteil *werde* vorerst nicht *vollstreckt werden.*)

(Beispiele aus Duden Band 4 – *Die Grammatik*)

Answer (score 0):

Die Konstruktion `würde werden` ist korrekt. Vergleiche:

> essen, aß: würde essen <-> äße
>
> wollen, wollte: würde wollen <-> wollte / (ugs.) wöllte
>
> werden, wurde: würde werden <-> würde

Die allgemeine Tendenz in der deutschen Sprache ist, Hilfsverben und Modalverben in der kurzen Form ausdrücken:

> **könnte** häufiger als **würde können**
>
> **wäre** häufiger als **würde sein**

Und demnach

> **würde** häufiger als **würde werden**

Das `würde werden` ist schon alleine deswegen selten anzutreffen, weil es redundant ist. Ein schöner Stil zeichnet sich durch Einfachheit aus. Wenn man ein ganzes Wort weglassen kann, ohne die Bedeutung zu ändern, dann tut man dies für gewöhnlich.

Comment: "Die allgemeine Tendenz in der deutschen Sprache ist, Hilfsverben und Modalverben in der kurzen Form ausdrücken" Hast Du eine Quelle dafür, oder ist das Dein Eindruck?

Comment: Die Tendenz zur Kurzform muss noch besser erklärt werden. Niemand verwendet z.B. "äße", weil das altmodisch klingt.

Comment: Ich bin mir nicht ganz sicher, aber die Langform mit "werden" wird doch gern verwendet, um Dinge zu betonen oder Wert auf den Verlauf bis zum zukünftigen Zeitpunkt zu legen (?).

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe mal eine Statistik angefertigt, in der ich 200 Vorkommen von *würde* untersucht habe, von 1000, die ich mir zufällig habe geben lassen (COSMAS II).

Die Zahlen sind wie folgt:

```
85 % irrelevant (würde + anderes Verb)
13 % würde allein
 2 % würde werden
```

Auf Grund der geringen Menge der relevanten Werte - 30 - ist das Verhältnis natürlich etwas ungenau, es sollte jedoch ausreichen, um die Tendenz darzustellen (86,67 % zu 13,33%).

Da ich ursprünglich die Fragestellung falsch in Erinnerung hatte, hatte ich vorher das Futur untersucht. Hier ergeben sich folgende Zahlen (auch 200 kodierte Belege):

```
70 % irrelevant (Futur oder Präsens anderes Verb)
26 % Präsens (wird)
 8 % Futur (wird werden)
```

Ich habe nach "voraussichtlich" gesucht, um Sätze zu finden, die fast immer einen deutlichen Zukunftsbezug haben.

"würde werden" ist vergleichsweise unsinnig, da der Infinitiv keinen Zusatzgewinn bringt und Sprecher faul sind. Also ist es nachvollziehbar, ihn wegzulassen.