# Übersetzung von »would be chosen«

Tags: subjunctive, passive, future

Wie könnte ich den folgenden Satz aus dem Englischen ins Deutsche übersetzen?

> An alternative option would be chosen.

Könnte ich Folgendes schreiben?

> Eine neue Option würde gewählt werden.

Das klingt irgendwie doppelt gemoppelt. Aber es ist doch richtig, oder?

Comment: Als wörtliche Übersetzung ist das korrekt. Es gibt vermutlich auch noch andere Möglichkeiten, den Satz zu übersetzen, z.B. als Aktiv. Aber dazu bräuchte man den Kontext.

Comment: Man bräuchte mehr Kontext, um hier wirklich gute Alternativen vorzuschlagen.

Comment: Doppelt gemoppelt wegen "würde ... werden"? Oder was bereitet Dir Sorgen?

Answer (score 3):

Die Übersetzung ist zwar korrekt, würde aber von einem deutschen Muttersprachler eher als steif bzw. als unelegant übersetzt empfunden werden. Geschmeidiger und verbreiteter wäre hier eine Übersetzung mit dem gefürchteten *„man“*:

> „Man würde nach einer Alternative suchen“

oder

> „Man würde sich für eine andere Option entscheiden“

oder

> „Man würde nach einer anderen Option suchen“.

Dabei eher *„anders“* als *„neu“* verwenden, da *„Option“* eine bereits zur Wahl stehende Alternative bezeichnet, keine erst noch neu zu entwickelnde Option. (Aber: Nie *„andere Alternative“*, da es sich hier um einen Pleonasmus handelte!)

Answer (score 2):

Ja, die Übersetzung ist korrekt, allerdings würde ich das zweite *werden* weglassen:

> Eine neue Option würde gewählt.

oder

> Eine andere Option würde gewählt.

Siehe auch folgende Frage: ["würde" vs "würde ... werden": Häufigkeit der Konjunktiv II Form von "werden"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18224/w%c3%bcrde-vs-w%c3%bcrde-werden-h%c3%a4ufigkeit-der-konjunktiv-ii-form-von-werden)